# My Table isn't sorting when sorting A to Z or Z to A with bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--Data Table Sortable Start-->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<!--Data Table Sortable Start-->
<!--Bootstrap End-->
<!-- Our Files -->
<link rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="images/house_icon.png"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
 <script defer src="/user_interface.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/user-interface.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/nav-bar.css"/>
</head>
<body>


<!-- Generator Sites Start-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="generator-wrapper text-center" id="generator-section">          
            <div class="generator-list">
                <table id="generator-table" data-toggle="generator-table" data-sort-order="desc">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-light table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="miles" data-sort-order="desc">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="generator-header" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Generator Sites</th>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th data-field="miles" data-sortable="true">Distance (Miles)</th>
                                <th data-field="feet" data-sortable="true">Distance (Feet) </th>
                                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Generator Name </th>
                                <th> Generator Address </th>
                                <th data-field="type" data-sortable="true">Generator Type(s) </th>
                            </tr>                                   
                            <tbody id="generator-body">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <script>
                            $(function() {
                              $('#sortable').change(function () {
                                $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                                  sortable: $('#sortable')
                                })
                              })
                            })
                        </script>
                    </div>      
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<!--Generator Sites Table End -->
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to sort different columns in my Table from A to Z and Z to A.
I have been able to get this to work previously but now it is not working since I changed my code  to bootstrap 4  How do I get my table to work with bootstrap 4 and do I need Javascript code?
I followed an example in the  https://bootstrap-table.com/ but I am still having issues getting my code to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--Data Table Sortable Start-->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<!--Data Table Sortable Start-->
<!--Bootstrap End-->
<!-- Our Files -->
<link rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="images/house_icon.png"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
 <script defer src="/user_interface.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/user-interface.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/nav-bar.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Generator Sites Start-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="generator-wrapper text-center"  id="generator-section">         
            <div class="generator-list">
                <table id="generator-table" data-toggle="generator-table" data-sort-order="desc">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-light table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="miles" data-sort-order="desc">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="generator-header" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Generator Sites</th>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th data-field="miles" data-sortable="true">Distance (Miles)</th>
                                <th data-field="feet" data-sortable="true">Distance (Feet) </th>
                                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Generator Name </th>
                                <th> Generator Address </th>
                                <th data-field="type" data-sortable="true">Generator Type(s) </th>
                            </tr>                                   
                            <tbody id="generator-body">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <script>
                            $(function() {
                              $('#sortable').change(function () {
                                $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                                  sortable: $('#sortable')
                                })
                              })
                            })
                        </script>
                    </div>      
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<!--Generator Sites Table End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be much easier to sort your dataset and then recreate the table.

Comment: A `for` loop inside a `while` loop... That sounds like something's really wonky here

Answer (score -1):

Check out [sorttable,js](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) — it will let you do **exactly** what you're trying to and is **stupidly easy to set up**.

You can make your table in regular HTML and then set its class to `"sortable"` after including this script to make the headers sort in ascending/descending order when you click them.

Comment: Not the one that downvoted you, but it's generally viewed poorly to suggest to use a library instead of providing a pure code answer when the OP asking a question isn't asking for one. The reason is that the library might become out of date in the future, or simply removed in which case, when a new user comes to see this question in the future, they may not be able to use your answer.

Comment: Unfortunate that this is still the only attempt at an answer...